# Does the word "unnoticed" act as an adverb or an adjective in the phrase "go unnoticed"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

In the sentence

> Steve went unnoticed by the crowd.

Does unnoticed modify *went*, making it an adverb or *Steve*, making it an adjective?

Comment: Verbs of perception and linking verbs normally take adjective complements. Here, if *went unnoticed by the crowd* means *became invisible to the crowd*, it's a subject complement. Whereas if it means *left secretly*, it's an adverb.

Comment: @mahmudkoya Add some spice and turn that into an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think "unnoticed" is ever an adverb—certainly not in the sentence "Steve went unnoticed by the crowd." It is an adjective.

Verbs can take adjectives as complements: the most obvious examples are copular verbs like "be" and "become". We say things like "Steve was unnoticed" or "Steve became unhappy" where "unnoticed" and "unhappy" are adjectives that act as complements to "was" and "became". Not everything that "modifies" or goes with a verb is an adverb (for comparison, a transitive verb can take a noun phrase as a direct object: that obviously doesn't make the noun phrase an adverb!).